# Google Play Developer API - C# - Sample does not work

Tags: c#, google-play

New to using Google Play API's. Trying to get their sample working.

https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/get_started

Their `using` statements,

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Google.Apis.Discovery.v1;
using Google.Apis.Discovery.v1.Data;
using Google.Apis.Services;
```

And the line(s) that doesn't work -

```
var service = new DiscoveryService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
            {
                ApplicationName = "Discovery Sample",
                ApiKey = "[YOUR_API_KEY_HERE]",
            });
foreach (DirectoryList.ItemsData api in result.Items)
```

Not sure if it ever worked for anyone, but I can't seem to locate the namespace for `DiscoveryService` and `DirectoryList`. 
[image]

Does anyone know which namespace `DiscoveryService` and `DirectoryList` belongs to? I tried to explore in Object Browser, but can't locate these classes/methods.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to find it! Had to install `Google.Apis.Discovery.v1` nugget package, it was missing before.

`using Google.Apis.Discovery.v1;` -> `new DiscoveryService()`

`using Google.Apis.Discovery.v1.Data;` -> `DirectoryList.ItemsData`

All good now.